# installing cakephp 3 manually, without composer

Tags: php, cakephp, installation, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I need to install CakePHP 3 in an old-fashioned *upload-unzip-run* way.

The archive I've downloaded from [cakephp/cakephp/tags](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags) does not contain the default folders like `webroot`, `Model` etc., which means it's not complete.

The [official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html) does not cover this. [Here's a relevant Github issue](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues/1606) I found, but the person ends up still using Composer.

There's also [cakephp/app](https://github.com/cakephp/app) and it seems to include those missing files, but it's not mentioned in `cakephp/cakephp`'s composer.json, and even if I download it I've no idea how to merge the packages.

Comment: Exactly why do you want to avoid using Composer? It's installed easily and the simplest way of getting Cake up and running.

Comment: For the first time you have to install it by composer later you can reuse that one or you can download from the git repository.

Comment: Because composer is a horrible way to manage dependencies. Bundling as composer does has never been a good idea.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Packaged app (`cakephp/app`) releases that include all dependencies (framework (`cakephp/cakephp`), standard CakePHP plugins (`cakephp/debugkit`, `cakephp/bake`, etc), required third party libraries) can be found on GitHub.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases**

It's the download with the small package symbol, named like `cake-3-x-x.zip`.

However, it isn't a good idea to ditch the dependency manager, as keeping the code base and the autoloader up to date will be rather tedious, and, no offense, I have my doubts that you'll be able to handle this properly if you don't even know how to stitch the app and cake packages together.

Answer (score 8):

You can install **CakePhp 3** without **Composer**.

You need minimum **requirements** to install CakePhp 3 and CakePhp 3 **boilerplate** ( fresh copy of Cakephp 3 ).

You can download CakePhp 3 boilerplate from github.

**Requirements**

**Server**

1. HTTP Server. For example: Apache. Having mod_rewrite is preferred,but by no means required.
2. PHP 5.4.16 or greater.
3. mbstring extension
4. intl extension

**Database :**

1. MySQL (5.1.10 or greater)
2. PostgreSQL
3. Microsoft SQL Server (2008 or higher)
4. SQLite 3

All built-in drivers require **PDO**. You should make sure you have the correct **PDO** extensions installed.

**CakePhp 3 Boilerplate:**

Repository Home

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases

CakePhp 3.1.4 
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/download/3.1.4/cakephp-3-1-4.zip
CakePhp 3.0.15
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/download/3.0.15/cakephp-3-0-15.zip

Download one repository and unzip where you wanted to install it.

You may get one error like ( you may not get error if you are lucky!)

```
Fatal Error 
Cake\Error\FatalErrorException
Error: Class 'Cake\Mailer\Email' not found 
File D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\cakephp\cakephp-3-1-4\config\bootstrap.php 
Line: 138
```

Then you have to comment two line in config/bootstrap.php

```
//Email::configTransport(Configure::consume('EmailTransport'));
//Email::config(Configure::consume('Email'));
```

And finally you got CakePhp 3 installed.

***[I am also new in CakePhp 3.So Please inform me if there are any wrong in my given process.]***

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Composer.

Install Composer locally, follow the Cake installation instructions, then upload the created folders to the target webhost.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this doesn't answer my question, sorry.

Comment: The longer answer is that Cake does heavily rely on Composer to create the autoloading. While in theory you could do this yourself with the same or worse results, why would you invest time in avoiding Composer and doing the same thing different. Invest time to make Composer run. You will benefit instantly at the very moment you want to add another PHP library for some special case.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, For CakePHP 3.x you can just download the release you want from here 
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases (eg. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/3.3.16).

**For a complete installation select the first download link (.zip)**

the other links are just for the src

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command to get a clone of **CakePHP 3.10.0**

```
git clone -b 3.x git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try simple steps
1. Download XAMPP Server.
2. Install XAMPP server.
3. Go to ..\xampp\php\php.ini and open. 
4. Add this line (extension=php_intl.dll) or if exist uncomment.
5. Download Composer setup from https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/releases/
6. Install composer and give php.exe file in path
7. Open cmd and check now php version using command php -v. if its showing php version its means its working.
8. Now open cmd and cd  on xampp\htdocs folder & run command composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app app_name
9. Finished folder created in htdocs.
```