# Can I create CakePHP 3.x project without composer?

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.x

I AM using `XAMPP3.2.1` which has the below configuration.

```
PHP5.6.14
MYSQL5.0.11
APache2.4.17
```

I have changed `extension=php_intl.dll` setting in `php.ini` file.

After I ran this `composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app [app_name]` my project created partially i.e vendor folder is empty.
Can i get zip file like `cakephp2X`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installing cakephp 3 manually, without composer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412844/installing-cakephp-3-manually-without-composer)

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp), you can get the latest release (at the time of writing this) from [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/download/3.1.4/cakephp-3-1-4.zip) as a ZIP file.

However, creating the project with composer is the preferred approach; since this creates a lot of output, retry and check for errors.

Comment: In addition to the Core code linked in this answer you will probably also need the APP skeleton, available [here](https://github.com/cakephp/app). - But as alread mentioned it's recommended to use composer...