# Can't not find the config/app.default.php in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I cloned the Cakephp source code from github and follow the cookbook to get started.
But it confuse me a lot for many files mentioned in the cookbook missing in the github repository.
Say `config/app.default.ph`p (Cookbook3.x p341), I want to configure the database connection, but there is no directory name `config` on **github**, and the only `App.php` I could found is in the Core directory, and it isn't look like a configuration file at all.
Is it wrong for me to just clone the source code from github?
I can't install cakephp with composer, I have to install cakephp in the source code way.

ps．Win7 + php5.6 + cakephp 3.1.7

Comment: Take a good hard look again into https://github.com/cakephp/app/tree/master/config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installing cakephp 3 manually, without composer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412844/installing-cakephp-3-manually-without-composer)

Comment: Why can't you use Composer to install CakePHP?

Comment: @mark Thanks a lot. I was reading the cookbook 2.x p36 and followed the instruction to cloned the github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git. But it seems like that it's not the application repositroy. Now I am ok with the installation, but I am still confused with the difference between cakephp/cakephp and cakephp/app.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja It's about the Internet blocked, can't connect to the distribute server.

Comment: Blocked inet for a developer is like a painter with his hands tied behind his back. It does not really work out either way. Best to use proxy tunnels or sth, but trying to workaround the issue is not sth for the long run (or move to a better suited country).